# Improving the response when an Ajax call add a new record

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following inside my asp.net mvc web application view:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateVMNetwork", "VirtualMachine", new AjaxOptions

{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "networktableBody",
    LoadingElementId = "progress",
    HttpMethod= "POST",
}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.TechnologyIP2.TechnologyID)

 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div>
<span class="f">IP Address</span> 

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TechnologyIP2.IPAddress)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechnologyIP2.IPAddress)                                              


 <span class="f"> MAC Address</span>       
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TechnologyIP2.MACAddress)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechnologyIP2.MACAddress)                                              


</div>

<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}
<div id ="CreateEditNetwork"></div>
 <p><img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress" /></p>
<table id= "networktable">
```

The above will call an action method that creates a new record and return a table row:-

```
<tr id="@Model.ID">
    <td> @Model.IPAddress</td> 

    <td>@Model.MACAddress</td>
    <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
 "DeleteNetworkInfo", "VirtualMachine",
new { id = Model.ID },

new AjaxOptions
{ Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete (" + Model.IPAddress + ")" + "( " + Model.MACAddress + ").",
    HttpMethod = "Post",

    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
})</td>
    </tr>
```

The above is working well, but sometimes the users will NOT notice that a new row was added to the table , so how I can improve my Ajax response so that users will be notify that the record was added successfully ?
Thanks

Comment: How do the users not notice? Are the new rows added to the end of the table? If you want the user to be notified I'd suggest some sort of alert or notification script which can be called from OnSuccess (This is an ajax option which can be added alongside your existing ones)

Comment: the row will be at the beginignof the table, but still not very clear to thensuers..

Comment: Ok. I would definitely recommend taking advantage of the OnSuccess callback to notify the user

Comment: the problem with the Onsuccess is that it might fire even if the creation was not success, this script will fire if the ajax.beginform recive a response even if it is an error ..

Comment: OnSuccess will only be fired if a successful response comes back. OnFailure will catch an unsuccessful response. Your service shouldn't be sending back a 200 code if it failed.

Comment: so in my case if the creation was success i will return a partial view, so does this equal to sending a 200 code ??

Comment: Yes - If its successful you will have a partial view in your ajax response and it will then trigger your OnSuccess callback. If an exception caught on your controller it will return an error code and thus hit your onFailure callback.

Comment: on Success show some activity like use popup to display message that record added successfully